# Deploying files in Windows Store App

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, windows-store-apps

Normally when I am writing a desktop application (in Visual Studio) and need to include a certain file in the build directory I just use the 'Copy Always' option in the file properties.  However, I am finding that if I use this option in a Windows Store App, the file will appear in the build directory, but is nowhere to be found when the application is deployed.  I have tried marking the Build Action for the file as 'content' and a few others, but no luck.

How do I get my files to show up in the deployment directory?

Comment: Did you try to use resources?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I don't know?  Care to elaborate?  Embedded resources?

Comment: you can start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh710212.aspx

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Don't get me wrong, but I didn't ask a specific question on a Q&A site to just be linked to a very broad document.  I am sure that if I read enough docs I can figure it out, but I was hoping that someone had a similar problem and knew the answer right off of the bat.